# Google Analytics shows delayed data after removed filter

Tags: google-analytics

has anybody every experience delay in data between views on the same property before and after applying a filter on google analytics.
Basically I have an unfiltered view (View1) this view is showing let's say 100K users
I have another View ( View2) where i applied a filter which shows 20K . 
The very next day a removed the filter from (View2) but now when i compare the number on day0 both having no filter the number are not the same. View2 will have the data being updated and matching view 1 only 30 hours later.
I wonder if there is a way to completely reset the view as it seems that it is still filtering and then doing a computation on the background.

Thanks,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

removing filters only affects the data collected after the filter was removed, past data are not changed.

Answer (score 0):

For the current day the filters are reprocessed after midnight. Everything that has been previously filtered (previous days) can no longer be restored if it has been filtered.

Comment: my question is why for the current day is it applying some filters even though there is none is there a way to come back to the initial state? It is like even though the filter is no more it still tries to filter some data but after midnight just give the correct number

Comment: This is because it is Google Analytics that works this way. It does not update in real time on every change made, then at midnight it checks everything and realigns itself.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the delay was a google adwords account that was link incorrectly to GA and was causing lag on the data , once remove the data come back to normal